# Listing all references actually in use

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

In Visual Studio (Enterpris 2019) using NuGet Package Manager
is it possible to report all references used per project of the solution?
I am esp. interested in the NuGet packages and I noticed that my local repositories
get bloated with folders of older package versions.
Most of them empty with files that are ignored by git.

So a listing of all references actually in use would be helpful.
E.g. via Package Manager Console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By **Package Manager Console**, it could be done with it.

You should open the whole solution on VS2019, and then open **Package Manager Console**, then type:

```
Get-Package | Select-Object Id,Version,ProjectName
```

[image]

It will list all nuget references and their version per project of the solution.